# share TouchEvent between fragments

Tags: android, fragment, touch-event

I have 2 fragments, sharing the screen.
In both, there is a layout that is listening to TouchEvents.
When I start a TouchEvent on the first fragment, and then moving my finger on top of the second one, the TouchEvent is still received by the first one, and never by the second.
I've tried different options without success. Could it be a solution, to handle the TouchEvent from the activity, and then dispatching it to both fragments ?
Any clue is welcome =)

Comment: What method are you using to intercept the TouchEvent? When you intercept the touch event, what are you returning? I know you can get the desired behaviour with onInterceptTouchEvent by returning false, but that's for between views. No idea with fragments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok ! here is (very basically) how I managed that :
MyActivity.java :

```
private ArrayList<MyOnTouchListener> onTouchListeners = new  ArrayList<MusicShaker.MyOnTouchListener>(10);
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    for (MyOnTouchListener listener : onTouchListeners) {
        listener.onTouch(ev);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
public void registerMyOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener listener){
    onTouchListeners.add(listener);
}
public interface MyOnTouchListener {
    public void onTouch(MotionEvent ev);
}
```

Fragment1.java :

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).registerMyOnTouchListener(new MyActivity.MyOnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
            Log.d("", "Fragment1 got it");
        }
    });
```

Fragment2.java :

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).registerMyOnTouchListener(new MyActivity.MyOnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
            Log.d("", "Fragment2 got it");
        }
    });
```

It works, but if anyone has a better solution, I'm always listening =)

Edit: be careful using this solution, as the MotionEvent x and y will be the same as rawX and rawY (no longer converted to View's coordinates)